# Adding views to angular-seed project

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-applications, angular-seed

How do you add more views to an Angular-seed project?

I just started this project and wanted to add more views so I copied the view2 folder and renamed it view3 (did the same for all files in the folder containing a view2 variable) and then added it to the module.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.view1',
    'myApp.view2',
    'myApp.view3',
    'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

the view3.js file looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view3', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view3', {
  templateUrl: 'view3/view3.html',
  controller: 'View3Ctrl'
 });
}])

.controller('View3Ctrl', [function() {

}]);
```

Is there anything else angular-seed related you need to do because I'm getting these errors when I reload the page and I don't really know where to start with this. Been looking in the Bower_components folder but doesn't seem to be anything in there that you're supposed to alter.

The third row talks about loading it, but loading it where?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.view3 due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.view3' is not available! You either misspelled the module     name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the   second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp.view3
at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1677:17
at ensure (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1601:38)
at module (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1675:14)
at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3878:22
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:18)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3872:5)
at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3879:40
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:18)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3872:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp.view3&p1=Err…ocalhost%3A8000%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3872%3A5)
at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3906:15
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:18)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3872:5)
at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3879:40
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:18)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3872:5)
at createInjector (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3812:11)
at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1444:20)
at bootstrap (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1459:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…calhost%3A8000%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1459%3A12)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the view3.js script in your index.html too.